# Can't unwind to UITableviewController using unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5, unwind-segue

I have a `UINavigationController` with the following hierarchy:

tableViewController -> detailView1 -> detailView2.

From `detailView2` I am trying to return to `tableViewController` using an unwind seque. But nothing happens.

In TableViewController there is the unwind method

```
@IBAction func unwindTest( _ seg: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

The detailView2 has a button. This triggers the unwind segue. This done bu dragging from button to the exit in this ViewController

Note:
When I tried replacing `UITableviewController` with `UIViewController` the unwind segue works.

Comment: You unwind to the previous UIViewCOntroller in the stack, so DetailsView1 in this case.  If you want more help you'll need to provide more detail of how you are implementing it.

Comment: Added more details. I want skip detailView1 and unwind to tableviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

The custom class for the UITableviewController was not set. Once set the unwind segue worked correctly.